# Browser Custom Protocol unsafe

Tags: safari, url

Using other helpful answers on the StackExchange community I have a custom URI protocol registered on a client's machine. It points to a simple AppleScript that we can then change as needed. In testing on our Mac here, it works without issue with a link formatted like:

`oururl://path/here`

However, when trying to click that url on their machines, in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, the URL is automatically changed to:

`unsafe:oururl://path/here`

So far I've been unable to find any additional information on why the "unsafe:" prefix is being added or how to address it. Any insight or workarounds?

Version info:
OSX 10.6.8
Safari 5.1.10 (6534.59.10)
Firefox 26.0
Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was much simpler than I thought (as usually happens in software development). Somehow I didn't catch this until user testing, which is what threw me in the direction of thinking it was a Mac issue. It is not a Mac issue.

I'm using the AngularJS framework and one of its "features" is to mark unknown protocols with an unsafe prefix. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page) to configure it to recognize mine and now all is well.